# Calculating age with current date and birth date in Java

Tags: java, datetime

I'm just starting out with java, and i'm making a program that determines a person's car rental rates, based on age and gender. This method is calculating the person's age based off of the current date and their birth date. it sort of works, but there's a problem with borderline cases (for example sometimes it will say you're 25 when you're 24). How can i fix it to make it return the exact age instead of it saying you're 1 year older sometimes? (and please no Joda, i can't use it in this assignment)

```
public static int calcAge(int curMonth, int curDay, int curYear,int birthMonth,int   birthDay,int birthYear) {

  int yearDif = curYear - birthYear;
  int age = 08;
  if(curMonth < birthMonth) {
     age = yearDif - 1;
     }
  if(curMonth == birthMonth) {
     if(curDay < birthDay) {
        age = yearDif - 1;
        }
     if(curDay > birthDay) {
        age = yearDif;
        }
     }
  if(curMonth > birthMonth) {
     age = yearDif;
     }

  return age;
  }
```

Comment: That doesn't compile in Java, so, what is the real code?  And what are the inputs that generate incorrect output?

Comment: this is just the method that calculates the age.

Comment: I think the `int age=08;` is causing a problem here. When an integer begins with a `0` it is interpreted as an octal not a decimal.. so help me out here, why do you set the age?

Comment: Actually i did catch that just as i posted it, but that was just me hitting the keyboard somehow. It wasn't part of the code when i ran it.

I set the age to 0 because it for some reason does not reassign the variable if it wasn't already set.

Comment: For what input does it say 25 when it should be 24?

Comment: for instance if i put in a birthdate of 2-2-1988 and a current date of 2-1-2013 it will return 25, when in fact that person doesn't turn 25 until the day after.

Comment: are you sure you didn't accidentally switch birthdate and current date? I just did and the result was **-25** (negative). while in the right order (2-1-2013 as current and 2-2-1988 as birth) gave 24 (positive)

Comment: Nope! mine's coming out positive.

Comment: I want to put this as answer, but it gives to much away. Technically, there are 365.242 days per year and 30.4368 days per month.  You could use this to convert the date values to the number of days since 0/0/000 and subtract the difference, converting the value back to years (which will give you a double, but with a cast to `int`, to will give you close approximation of the age in years).  In my testing, it passed both your tests - just as another possibility ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can use Java 8, it's much better than joda:

```
    LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1982, 01, 29);
    long yearsDelta = birthday.until(LocalDate.now(), ChronoUnit.YEARS);
    System.out.println("yearsDelta = " + yearsDelta);
```

Comment: AFAIK - is based on the JodaTime library - I think basically, they have to do it manually for the assignment, no 3rd party and build in libraries ;)

Comment: JDK 8 date time library (JSR 310) is written by the same author as the Joda library and is considered a much improved rewrite. If the OP can't even use old java.util.Date, then this sounds like some artificial homework exercise and all this is moot.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's very helpful to me and yes, I believe that's my point, hence I didn't jump down your throat or downvote your answer, but it still fails to answer the OP's question ;)

Comment: Doing this without _any_ libraries is hard when you consider all the weird rules regarding leap years and such.

Comment: Well unless the person was born on Feb 29th, leap years wouldn't really have any difference considering the required level of sophistication for this. Even then this would still give a good enough approximation.

Comment: @user2684301 Don't disagree, hence the reason I turn to things like JodaTime when I need to do this, but that's the requirements handed to the OP.  It's probably more about problem solving then producing an accurate answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

You need to check for equals when you are comparing the days e.g

```
else if (curDay >= birthDay) {
    age = yearDif;
}
```

instead of

```
if(curDay > birthDay) {
    age = yearDif;
}
```

Comment: yes, when testing, I saw that there where some cases left unhandled. Either test for equality, or initialize age with yearDif right at the beginning.

Comment: I don't want to give the full answer so you can learn however instead of having all the if statements you should try and use else if and else. Check out the Java tutorial on Control Flow here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: I did try that, but that makes the program work incorrectly for some reason.

Comment: Can you post that code? We can probably figure out what went wrong. As I've made those edits to your code and tested with the dates causing you issue and gotten 24. e.g. I called calcAge(2,1,2013,2,2,1988)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use "Date" to convert both times to epoch milliseconds and then simply subtract these and get the difference converted back to year values by simple math. Get it? This would be without any extra libraries :)

Comment: can't use date either.

Comment: What is preventing you? I see no reason for that.

Comment: I don't think they are allowed to as part of the assignment *"i can't use it in this assignment"* :P

Comment: Well then of course yiu manually could convert it to epoch milliseconds.  That's a little nasty but should even work in this assignment.